# Skipping if statments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested

I created nested conditions in my lines of code, but i want to skip them if any of the other "(book) condition" conditions isn't "good".

```
condition = input("What is the condition of the book? ")
age = input("Is the book old or new? ")
cover = input("What type of cover does it have? ")


if condition == "good":
    if age == "new":
        if cover == "hardcover":
            print("We can offer you a high price")
        elif cover == "papercover":
            print("We can offer you a medium price")
    elif age == "old":
        print("We can offer you a medium price")
elif condition == "poor":
    print("We can offer a low price")
elif condition == "terrible":
    print("Sorry we cannot accept this book")
else:
    print("I do not understand, please leave the store")
```

Comment: What do you mean "skip them"? Can you show what you want to happen with a specific input?

Comment: For the first statement, if I entered in 'good' it will go through the other statement as how I wanted. But if entered 'poor', then I will continue to go through the other statements. I basically want to skip pass the "age" and "cover" statements if i put in "terrible" or "poor"

Comment: If you do not input `'good'` you will skip the age and cover things ... they _are_ only executed fot `'good'` books.I do not get you

Comment: If I put in either 'poor' or 'terrible' I still have to do the 'age' and 'cover' statements even though I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

you need to move your input into the if statements, that way you use the already existing if-else structure, like this:

```
condition = input("What is the condition of the book? ")

if condition == "good":
    age = input("Is the book old or new? ")
    if age == "new":
        cover = input("What type of cover does it have? ")
        if cover == "hardcover":
            print("We can offer you a high price")
        elif cover == "papercover":
            print("We can offer you a medium price")
    elif age == "old":
        print("We can offer you a medium price")
elif condition == "poor":
    print("We can offer a low price")
elif condition == "terrible":
    print("Sorry we cannot accept this book")
else:
    print("I do not understand, please leave the store")
```

Comment: if this answer was correct consider marking it as such